# URISyntaxException in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to copy data from local to Hadoop ecosystem but when I execute the command I get the following error:unexpected URISyntaxException

The Command that i am using is

```
hadoop fs -put "/home/cloudera/Desktop/<filename.txt>"  <Hadoop folder Name>
```

I have used the copyFromLocal command also. Still getting the same error.

Also when mentioning the hadoop folder name, do I have to specify the path of the folder?

Comment: Try using file:// in front of your file name.

Comment: I have tried that, but it says : the file does not exist